# openssl_encrypt возвращает false если использовать OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING

Tags: php, openssl

Получаю некоторые зашифрованные данные из стороннего сервиса и на `php` их успешно дешифрую следуюющим кодом

```php
$secret = 'test';
$iv = '1234567890123456';
$algo = 'aes-256-cbc';

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encryptedString, $algo, $secret, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
```

Пытаюсь зашифровать тем же способом с теми же настройками

```php
...
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($phone, $algo, $secret, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
```

Но с функции `openssl_error_string()` получаю ошибку *error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length* если использую опцию `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`

Следующий код работает но дает мне не то что нужно в результате

```php
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($phone, $algo, $secret, $options=0, $iv);
```

Изменить данные для шифрования/дешифрования не могу, т.к они задаються на стороннем сервере, а шифровать мне нужно для тестирования.

Answer (score 1):

Опция `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` означает, что ваши данные шифруются как есть, без выравнивания на границу блока.

Сообщение об ошибке говорит: длина строки `$phone` не кратна размеру блока.

В AES размер блока данных 128 бит, поэтому перед шифрованием вам нужно самостоятельно дополнить `$phone` до 128 бит.

Comment: Да верно. С самого начала не мог понять в чем причина. Но потом пришел к такому же заключению в своем ответе поделился кодом который дополняет строку не достающими битами.

Answer (score 0):

Немного поискал на stackoverflow на английском нашел решение проблемы. Дело в том что текст должен быть в длинну блока. Нашел решение [в этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181905/mcrypt-encrypt-to-openssl-encrypt-and-openssl-zero-padding-problems)

Немного доработал код под себя

```php
function makePadding(string $source, string $iv): string
{
    $ivLength = strlen($iv);

    if (strlen($source) % $ivLength) {
        return str_pad($source, strlen($source) + $ivLength - strlen($source) % $ivLength, "\0");
    }

    return $source;
}
```